# how is the search property strategy for __name__ in Python different from normal strategy?

Tags: python

For example, I define a class:

```
class Test(object):
    pass
print dir(Test)
```

getting the following result:

```
['__class__','__delattr__','__dict__','__doc__','__format__','__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__','__reduce__','__reduce_ex__', '__repr__','__setattr__','__sizeof__','__str__','__subclasshook__','__weakref__']
```

print Test.**name** gettting the following result:
Test

my question is there is no **name** in Test, why can print Test.**name**, what is the searching stratrgy of **name**;

any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `dir` of `Test.__class__`, because `__name__` is defined on the `type` type:

```
>>> Test.__name__
'Test'
>>> Test.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> dir(Test.__class__)
[..., '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', ...]
```

If something can't be found on a class (instance of `type`) it's looked up in its meta class of the class which is (usually) `type`.

Comment: wouldn't the function dir() list all the property that the object defined or inherited from its base class?

Comment: Yes all the properties defined on it's base class. However dir(Test) is returning the properties of a `class` object. `class` itself doesn't have a "base class" per se, just a meta class `type`.

Comment: oh, I understand, dir() would not list all the properties in its and its base classes. when you Test.__name__, the property searching strategy would gradually goto its base class for __name__.    Thank you very much @Sebastian Wozny